# Getting the title, author, etc. of a PDF using ABCpdf

Tags: abcpdf

I am using ABCpdf, and simply cannot obtain the title or author of a document programmatically. Cannot seem to find any good examples on WebSupergoo's site!  Must be a simple issue.

```
Doc d = new Doc();
d.Read(path);
var y = d.GetInfo(d.Root, "/Title:Text");
var x = d.GetInfo(d.Root, "/publicfilePath:Text");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK very very simple in the end.

This is how I am adding the information

```
            int theID = doc.AddObject("<< >>");
            doc.SetInfo(-1, "/Info:Ref", theID.ToString());

            publicPath = base.GetPublicSavePath(FilePrefix);
            doc.SetInfo(theID, "/Title:Text", "here is where the title goes");
            doc.SetInfo(theID, "/Author:Text", "WebSupergoo");
            doc.SetInfo(theID, "/publicfilePath:Text", publicPath);

            doc.Save(publicPath);
```

This is how I need to obtain it

```
        var a = d.GetInfo(-1, "/Info/publicfilePath");
        var b = d.GetInfo(-1, "/Info/Title");
```

Comment: Fantastic ! Exactly what I was looking for !